# Select data in single row for multi records of an ID from table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have the following table in PostgreSQL database

[image: Table]

I want a query that can produce following results.

[image: Required Result]

Thank you

Comment: Why not simply `select *` and have your app or website put this in a grid/table? Seems the straight-forward way to me.

Comment: SQL queries return before known columns. You want the columns "record_id", "183", "184" and "185". So if there is a node_id 186 in the table, we ignore this record, correct?

Comment: record_id + node_id are a unique key for the table, yes?

Comment: Actually, I am facing difficulty to show tables to show data properly, however, I have edited the question and insert pictures of tables.

Comment: Yes Thorsten Kettner record_id and node_id(node) are unique keys and comes from other tables. For every reocrd_id I need a single row of data

Comment: The request was much better with the tables as text. Why did you change this to image links? And my question again: You want three before-known values (e.g. 183, 185, 186). Other values will be ignored. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct. I need values of wfstate in a row against these three values(183, 185, 186) for each record_id. How can I get this

Comment: Then Ankit Bajpai's query will work for you. (There is only a minor typo in it; the closing parenthesis belongs after `END` not before it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregate.

```
SELECT record_id,
       max(case when node = 'A' then state end) as A,
       max(case when node = 'B' then state end) as B,
       max(case when node = 'C' then state end) as C
FROM table1 
group by record_id
order by record_id;
```

*OR*

```
SELECT record_id,
       min(case when node = 'A' then state end) as A,
       min(case when node = 'B' then state end) as B,
       min(case when node = 'C' then state end) as C
FROM table1 
group by record_id
order by record_id;
```

**Result:**

```
record_id   a   b   c
----------------------
1000000     CC  CC  CC
1000001     CC  CC  CC
1000002     CC  CC  CC
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/XWD26502)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT record_id
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Node = 'A' THEN state) END AS A
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Node = 'B' THEN state) END AS B
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Node = 'C' THEN state) END AS C
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY record_id
```

Comment: Hi Ankit Bajpai thanks for help: This query is showing error.

Comment: Move the parentheses: `MAX(CASE WHEN Node = 'A' THEN state END) AS A`.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks both of you (Ankit Bajpai & Thorsten Kettner)